# Callback email check

Tags: php, codeigniter

Trying to set-up a call back function, but it's not working for some reason. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Look for the registration() and _email_check($str) functions in the controller below.

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Register extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this -> load -> model('user_model');
}

public function index() 
{
    if (($this -> session -> userdata('user_name') != "")) {
        redirect('dashboard');
    } 
    else
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Register';
        $this -> load -> view('shared/header_view', $data);
        $this -> load -> view("registration.php", $data);
        $this -> load -> view('shared/footer_view', $data);
    }
}

public function login() 
{
    $email = $this -> input -> post('email');
    $password = $this -> input -> post('pass');

    $result = $this -> user_model -> login($email, $password);
    if ($result)
        redirect('dashboard');
    else
        $this -> index();
}

public function registration() 
{
    $this -> load -> library('form_validation');
    // field name, error message, validation rules
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('email_address', 'Your Email', 'trim|required|valid_email', 'callback__email_check');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('con_password', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');

    if ($this -> form_validation -> run() == FALSE) 
    {
        $this -> index();
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this -> user_model -> add_user();

        $email = $this -> input -> post('email');
        $password = $this -> input -> post('pass');            

        $result = $this -> user_model -> login($email, $password);
        if ($result)
        {
            redirect('dashboard');  
        }          
    }        
}

// Checks that Email Address is not in use
public function _email_check($str)
{
    // return true if the address is indeed a new address
    $this -> db -> where('email', $str);
    $found = $this -> db -> get('user') -> num_results(); // this returns the number of rows having the same address.

    if ($found!=0)
    {
        $this -> form_validation -> set_message('email_check', 'Email Address is already in use');
        return false;  // more than 0 rows found. the callback fails.
    }
    else
    {
        return true;   // 0 rows found. callback is ok.
    }
}

public function logout() 
{
    $newdata = array('user_id' => '', 'user_name' => '', 'user_email' => '', 'logged_in' => FALSE, );
    $this -> session -> unset_userdata($newdata);
    $this -> session -> sess_destroy();
    redirect(base_url());
}
}
```

Here's the MODEL in case you need it:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function login($email, $password) 
{
    $this -> db -> where("email", $email);
    $this -> db -> where("password", $password);

    $query = $this -> db -> get("user");
    if ($query -> num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $rows) 
        {
            //add all data to session
            $newdata = array(
                'user_id' => $rows -> id,
                'user_name' => $rows -> username,
                'user_email' => $rows -> email,
                'logged_in' => TRUE,
            );
        }
        $this -> session -> set_userdata($newdata);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function add_user() 
{
    $data = array(
        'username' => $this -> input -> post('user_name'),
        'email' => $this -> input -> post('email_address'),
        'password' => $this -> input -> post('password'),
    );
    $this -> db -> insert('user', $data);
}
}
```

Comment: "not working". ah, that ever so useful diagnostic. I'm going to assume that this code is kicking your dog, so I'll suggest that you take away the code's boots so it doesn't hurt the dog as much.

Comment: Always an ass kicking around here...Obviously most would assume the call back function is not working. To spell it out, it's not returning with an error that the email address is valid or invalid. Function (_email_check($str)) doesn't seem to be executing. Entering an email address already on the database should generate an error message when registering. it's not.

Comment: There... that wasn't so hard. 3 extra sentences and now we have an idea of what to look for. posting a wall of code and basically saying "it's broken, fix it", is not very well received here.

Comment: Basic trouble shooting. Make the first two lines in the callback: echo 'hi'; die; if your application greets you then you know it's calling the function and it's executing and failing somewhere else. Slowly run through it printing or echoing out the variables you're setting until you find the issue.

Comment: Thanks guys...appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugh... just told you to troubleshoot and the problem is you're calling the callback wrong.

```
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('email_address', 'Your Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback__email_check')
```

Comment: Glad to help! And honestly those troubleshooting methods weren't a waste of time, that's how I handle things everytime my application does something I don't expect it to (or doesn't do something I do expect it to)